# What are some good jQuery plugins for scale/rotate by touch?

Tags: jquery, touch

The ones I keep finding are either bad or not made for multiple touch points.

I'm looking for something like this: http://www.maximumpc.com/files/u57670/mediaapp_sm.png

Comment: +1 A very interesting question!

Answer (score -2):

I think you can find what you need right here:

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/w/list

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Comment: I was actually looking for something much more specific. Something with touch support and multiple touchpoints for scaling and rotating simultaneously. I will likely end up writing my own (maybe using your suggestions), but it seems like a common enough thing that someone must have written one before me.